# Struggling to understand a program that calculates the sum of numbers in hex, oct, bin and dec

Tags: c++

I've been struggling to understand how the function long long number here works. The bit that I can't fully grasp is the for cycles in the if's. Why when we have a number in dec do we have to raise it to that power? Shouldn't we just sum it up and leave it? Also why do we raise the other numbers to that power?

Here is the code:

```
int counter(long long n, int k) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        counter++;
        n /= k;
    }
    return counter;
}
int number2(long long n, int number) {
    return (n / (long long) pow(10, number)) % 10;
}
int toDecimal(long long n, int k) {
    long long decimal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter(n, 10); i++) {
        decimal += number2(n, i)*(int)pow(k, i);
    }
    return decimal;
}

long long number(char *arr, int start) {
    int end = start;
    long long number2 = 0;

    while (*(arr + end) != ' ' && *(arr + end) != '\0') {
        end++;
    }

    int numberSize = end - start;

    if (*(arr + start) != '0') {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberSize; i++) {
            number2 += (*(arr + start + i) - '0')*pow(10, numberSize - i - 1);
        }
        return number2;
    }

    if (*(arr + start) == '0' && (*(arr + start + 1) != 'b' && *(arr + start + 1) != 'x')) {
        for (int i = 1; i < numberSize; i++) {
            number2 += (*(arr + start + i) - '0')*pow(10, numberSize - i - 1);
        }
        return  toDecimal(number2, 8);
    }

    if (*(arr + start) == '0' && *(arr + start + 1) == 'b') {
        for (int i = 2; i < numberSize; i++) {
            number2 += (*(arr + start + i) - '0')*pow(10, numberSize - i - 1);
        }
        return  toDecimal(number2, 2);
    }

    if (*(arr + start) == '0' && *(arr + start + 1) == 'x') {

        int *hex = new int[numberSize - 2];

        for (int i = 2; i < numberSize; i++) {

            if (*(arr + start + i) >= '0'&&
                *(arr + start + i) <= '9')
                arr[i - 2] = (*(arr + start + i) - '0');

            if (*(arr + start + i) >= 'A'&&
                *(arr + start + i) <= 'F')
                arr[i - 2] = (int)(*(arr + start + i) - '7');
            number2 += arr[i - 2] * pow(16, numberSize - i - 1);

        }
        delete[] hex;
        return number2;
    }
}

int main() {
    char first[1000];
    cin.getline(first, 1000);

    int size = strlen(first);

    long numberr = number(&first[0], 0);
    for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++) {
        if (first[counter] == ' '&&first[counter + 1] == '+') {
            numberr += number(&first[0], counter + 3);
        }
    }
    cout << numberr << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm struggling too, because it has poor formatting and no documenting comments. I propose you ask the author of the code for their rationale.

Comment: That code is way over-complicated. One example, instead of having to look at `arr + start` everywhere, why wouldn't you just adjust the arr pointer at the beginning of the function to be `arr + start`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is a string and is a sequence of single characters representing digits. You have to convert the characters to numbers ("1" --> 1) and then multiply it by the right number of tens to move it to the right place. For example:  "123" -->  (1 * 10^2) + (2 * 10^1) + (3 * 10^0)

Comment: Aha, so that transfers the number from the array into an int. Thank you.